# Wikipedia Library shows error if input not given exactly to the name of a page of wikipedia

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

If I give a voice command using speech recognition module to search something in Wikipedia if I don't say exactly it shows an error. For example: I say(National Defence Academy) no Wikipedia page is named so but(National Defence Academy (India)) is a page, so it shows results. I want to search for the nearest page as per my voice command. Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import Wikipedia
import web-browser
import os
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
def voiceinput():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("I am listening")
        r.pause_threshold=1
        audio=r.listen(source)
try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        speak("Recognizing...")
        query=r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(f"You mean {query}\n")
        speak(f"You mean {query}\n")
except Exception as e:
        print("Please repeat")
        speak("please repeat?")
        return "None"
return query
if "search" in query:
    speak("Searching Wikipedia")
    query=query.replace("search", "")
    results=wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
    print("According to Wikipedia")
    print(results)
    speak("According to Wikipedia")
    speak(results)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar search has to be made in this case. You are using the **Wikipedia** package and not **Pywikibot** as tagged above. Anyway here is a code snippet how a **similar search** can be done with Pywikibot:

```
  >>> from difflib import get_close_matches
  >>> import pywikibot
  >>> site = pywikibot.Site('wikipedia:en')  # create a Site object
  >>> title = 'National Defence Academy'
  >>> gen = site.search('intitle:' + title, total=10, namespaces=0)
  >>> titles = [page.title() for page in gen]  # list of strings required
  >>> result = get_close_matches('National Defence Academy', titles)
  >>> found = pywikibot.Page(site, result[0])
```

`found` is a Page object with closest match of the given title. Get its text:

```
  >>> found.text[:100]
```

- Refer [Pywikibot documentation](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/stable/api_ref/pywikibot.site.html?highlight=search#pywikibot.site._generators.GeneratorsMixin.search) for further search details.
- Refer [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/difflib.html?highlight=get_close_matches#difflib.get_close_matches) for difflib details.